# Evaluate logrithmic integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Does the following expression converge? Where $n$ is positive integer $1,2,3,...$

$$\int_0^\infty(\ln x)^n dx$$

Comment: Diverges for even n.

Comment: @Edwin_R, how do you propose I go about evaluating it?

Comment: Why don't we just compare it with the integral of one from $e$ to $\infty$?

Comment: @Edwin_R Diverges for every $n$ I would claim...

Comment: @Thorben yes. and now i know, after reading your answer :-). i wrote that because it was obvious for even n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is correct,

A substitution $y=ln(x)$ gives,
$$\int_0^{\infty}\ln(x)^ndx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}y^ne^ydy=\int_{-\infty}^0y^ne^ydy+\int_0^{\infty}y^n e^ydy $$
where 
$$\int_{-\infty}^0y^ne^ydy=\int^{\infty}_0(-y)^ne^{-y}dy=(-1)^n\int^{\infty}_0y^ne^{-y}dy=(-1)^nn!$$
but 
$$
\int_0^{\infty}y^n e^ydy\geq\int_0^{\infty}y^ndy=\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n+1}y^{n+1}=\infty$$
Hence $\int_0^{\infty}\ln(x)^ndx$ is divergent for every $n\geq0$.

Comment: how can limits after substitution be same?In the first step.

Comment: @SA-255525 where do you mean? After substitution you integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Sorry I just see that i forget to put the minus in front of the lower limit...

Comment: Is  ln 0 = -inf.

Comment: @SA-255525 Yes, just plot $ln(x)$ somewhere and you will see what happends if $x$ tends to zero

Comment: Thanks very much I missed this point totally. And yes this integral is divergent for every n>=0. your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome! :D

Comment: Though it doesn't matter in proving that this term diverges, still can you explain how you got $\int_0^{\infty}y^n e^ydy=\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}n!(e^y-1)$. I think there would be more terms.

Comment: @Edwin_R why it does not matter? That this term diverges is exactly what shows that $\int_0^{\infty} ln(x)^ndx$ is divergent for every $n$. (It is actually the only important part in my calculation). I will show the last equality in an edit.

Comment: @Edwin_R I just realised that ther is a mistake in the end. I just corrected it, thanks for mentioning.

Comment: I mean it does not matter to 'evaluate' this integral. The integrand itself diverges. And is always positive. Hence integral diverges.

Comment: @Edwin_R ah ok, missunderstood you then :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use integration by parts to reduce the exponent step by step.
That will lead to a formula like this.
$$\int(\ln x)^n =x(\ln x)^n-n\int(\ln x)^{n-1}dx$$

Answer (score 2):

Split the interval $(0,\infty)$ into $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$. For the former, see [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#History). As for the latter, it clearly diverges, thus making the entire quantity divergent.